# Unable to install boto3 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, boto3

I'm trying to install boto3 on my Mac(10.11.4), but was not able to; here's the error.

I've tried to installed the latest pip, but still now working.

```
pip install boto3
Collecting boto3
  Using cached boto3-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Collecting botocore<1.5.0,>=1.4.1 (from boto3)
  Using cached botocore-1.4.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<1.5.0,>=1.4.1->boto3)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.5.0,>=1.4.1->boto3)
  Using cached docutils-0.12.tar.gz
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.5.0,>=1.4.1->boto3)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, docutils, botocore, boto3
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/2s/n6x417ts45g4bhqcl4bccz_8b6mvmh/T/pip-Er44rb-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: for sure I tried sudo, but no luck. and it's the exactly same error.

Comment: sudo pip install boto3 --ignore-installed six did work. Thanks.